# Having problems with Java ServerSocket.Accept()

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I have been having issues using server socket
I have these two methods

```
public boolean sendRequest(String IP, int port) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside network send");
        client = new Socket(IP, port);
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                client.getOutputStream());
        outToClient.writeBytes("Requesting Game\n");
        System.out.println("sent");
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String s = null;
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        while (true) {
            s = inFromClient.readLine();
            if (s != null) {
                if (s.equals("YES"))
                    return true;
                else if (s.equals("NO"))
                    return false;
                else return false;
            }
            long curr = new Date().getTime();
            if((curr-start) > (60*1000))
            {
                System.out.println("TIMEOUT IN receiving request response");
                return false;
            }
            //time out 1 minute
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And

```
public boolean receiveConnection() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside network rec");
        server.setSoTimeout(60*1000);
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Rec");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                client.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        while (true) {
            line = in.readLine();
            if (line != null)
                break;
            long curr = new Date().getTime();
            if((curr-start) > (60*1000))
            {
                System.out.println("TIMEOUT IN receiving connection");
                return false;
            }
            //time out 1 minute
        }
        if (line.equals("Requesting Game")) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

With this Class Constructor as follows

```
public Communicator() {
    try {
        // initialize a server on this pc
        // connection to other pcs are done on another method
        server = new ServerSocket(1234);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

now whenever I try to run this program on my machine with DIFFERENT PORT NUMBERS for this server It works perfectly

but when I try to play it on different machines and connect to their IP and port number correctly Sometimes it fails 
It gets the receiveConnection method gets stuck at server.accept() and the other one gets stuck at creating new Socket(IP,port)

I need to get help on this problem as communication has to be reliable
thanks

Comment: what you want to do is put accept() in an infinate loop, starting a new Thread to handle the sockets as they are accepted. otherwise your server can only handle one request at a time. this may be the cause of your problem (even if its not, its going to cause problems)

Comment: You have another problem. If `readLine()` returns true, or you get any other EOS indication, you must close the socket and exit the reading loop.

Comment: @EJP the problem is it sometimes doesn't get past the server.accept() line of code. And I have no idea why that sometimes works and other times it doesn't